# ASP.net MVC, I want one database, not multiple

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am following the guide on the asp.net site for learning asp.net mvc4.

Link : [www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/)

Thing is, I want to put my movies table in the Default connection. Because I want all of the data to be in ONE database and not two.

I mean. I am confused as to why I can't just have one database, with separate tables. Surely multiple databases will introduce latency, and also scalability issues to my project.

How can I get around this?

Comment: What, exactly, is preventing you from using a single database?

Comment: You seem to be making a lot of assumptions, all of which are incorrect.  Your data model is under your control, if you're ending up with more than one database, it's because you're doing something wrong, but your description is lacking information so we have no idea how to help you.

Comment: well... in my app_data folder, I only have one mdf file, which I guess is the database?

However, in Server Explorer, I have multiple contexts, and that is when following the tutorial to the letter.

One is called DefaultConnection and the other is MovieDBContext.

Comment: I know this is not too helpful but... you might need to start the tutorial from scratch and identfy exactly when you get two contexts.

Is your controller code actually using them both? You might find that only one of them is use and the other one was generated accidentally. I had a lot of issues working out how that dbContext stuff worked and personally I don't think it adds that much value!

Comment: Yeah, I am gonna start from scratch tomorrow... I have a lot of experience in development... and I am finding ASP.net mvc completely unintuitive in comparison to other systems I have built with the MVC design pattern

Comment: The connections available in the *Server Explorer* of Visual Studio are not necessarily the database(s) used in your projects.

Comment: Server explorer is a Visual Studio tool.  You could have 2000 databases listed in Server Explorer, and your app would only be using whatever database you configured it to use.

Comment: Bear in mind that you *may not* want your authentication data in the same database as your application data.

Answer (score 1):

That Default connection points to your local db and is what is used for the forms authentication stuff. That db has all of the asp.net role provider schema stuff in it and since it's an "internet" project this is where all the login stuff goes. if you want to have your entities and models hook into that same database when you add your entity framework model point it at that db and your good to go.

After a little further investigation: 
It looks like http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model is where you define your connection string for your entities. I noticed `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf` in there, and after verifying my thoughts http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/ it looks like that is what is spinning up a second database in the app's data directory called movies.mdf. If you want to keep your 1 default database, change the connection string information in your MovieDBContext string to that of the default connection and  and it should create your new movie structure within that same database.

Comment: Thanks, just need to ask you a quick question then... Since I have started all over to make sure I don't mess up again.

When I right click "controllers" then click add -> Controller.

I get the "Add Controller" Dialog.

I choose the MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using entity framework.

In the combo boxes for Model class and Data context class, I dont see default connection...